# How to use java code to invoke info-beamer

Tags: pi-3

Can i use java code to invoke info-beamer or is there any java API of info-beamer?

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://info-beamer.com/doc/info-beamer) it would appear the software is customizable only using Lua. As my search didnt find a public forum, I think you'd probably have better luck contacting the [author](https://info-beamer.com/doc/about) directly. There are some packages [available](http://elinux.org/RPi_Projects/Digital_Signage) you might want to check out (not much java based from what i can tell)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I didn't see this question earlier. info-beamer doesn't have a Java API. It exposes its functionality using Lua. But you can talk to the running visualization using (for example) the UDP protocol. This should be easily to do from Java. Have a look at these examples on how this might work: [UDP example](https://github.com/dividuum/info-beamer-nodes/tree/master/gauge), [TCP example](https://github.com/dividuum/info-beamer-nodes/tree/master/remote-controlled-slideshow)